# How to keep my main thread and p thread alive?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, cygwin

I have a main function which, has a while loop which is Keeping my program live , but when i call the another thread (which is required), my main thread exits or I have to suspend it by calling thread join, i don know if its my codes problem

I have a this function calling my thread

```
int start_sender_engine(void)
{
    thread1_ret = pthread_create(&Send_thread_1, NULL, Sender_thread,(void*) message1);
    //pthread_join(Send_thread_1, NULL);
    return 0;

}
```

im calling this thread here ,

now my main thread is like this

```
     int main (int argc, char *argv[])
        {
        
            start_sender_engine();
        
            while(1)
            {

            data.CommandCode=33+cont[0];
            data.DataSize=sizeof(cont);
            data.Data=cont;
    
            Enqueue_elements(queue_hndl, &data);
    
            usleep(1000*1000);
    
          }
        deleteQueue(queue_hndl);
}
```

my dequeue function is located inside the thread

```
void *Sender_thread(void *msg_ptr) // Sender Engine
{
    char *message;
    message = (char *) msg_ptr;
    printf("%s\n",message);
    fflush(stdout);


    
    /*
     * Create a datagram socket on which to send.
     */

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0) {
        perror("opening datagram socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a
     * group address of 225.1.1.1 and port 5555.
     */
    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.1.1.2");
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(65533);

    /*
     * Disable loopback so you do not receive your own datagrams.
     */
    {
        char loopch=0;

        if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP,
                (char *)&loopch, sizeof(loopch)) < 0) {
            perror("setting IP_MULTICAST_LOOP:");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams.
     * The IP address specified must be associated with a local,
     * multicast-capable interface.
     */
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.10");
    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF,
            (char *)&localInterface,
            sizeof(localInterface)) < 0) {
        perror("setting local interface");
        exit(1);
    }


    /*
     * Send a message to the multicast group specified by the
     * groupSock sockaddr structure.
     */



    //// Queue ////////
    queue_hndl = createQueue(1000, (sizeof(SenderData) + 5000) );

    while(stop_nw_global!=1)
    {

        if(no_elements(queue_hndl)>0)
        {
            temp=Dequeue_elements(queue_hndl);
            printf("CMD Code %d",temp->CommandCode);
            printf("---Size %d",temp->DataSize);
            int *testi = (int*)temp->Data;
            printf("Sending- %d\n", testi[0]);
            fflush(stdout);
            send_packets(*temp,100);
        }
        else
        {
            usleep(1000*1000);
            printf(".\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

when i comment pthread join, i get a error message as

```
>>>>>>Sender_Engine_Started<<<<<<<
      0 [main] nwudp 1647 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to 
      nwudp.exe.stackdump
.
```

when i un comment pthread join, my thread(Sender_thread)works perfectly, but my while loop inside my main stops

how can i make both alive? or should i create another thread for main?

Comment: Are you using any mutexes to control access to variables read/written by both threads?

Comment: @dbush yes im doing it for the queue, more over  there is no variable common to both threads

Comment: The posted code doesn't show that.  Also, the main thread and the sender thread use `queue_hndl` without a mutex.

Comment: Semantics of `join` is to wait for the joined thread to finish. So if you join immediately, your main thread of course is blocked. You indeed should join, but not before the worker thread indeed is intended to terminate, so you would do so *after* the while-loop inside main.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out the issue, my queue handle "queue_hndl" was being used in the mains while loop before it was initialized, it was getting initialized just before my thread starts , so i have changed it acquire handle before starting my thread and now it works